# software center crashes upon openinig in 12.04 - no error message

Tags: 12.04

I just completed a fresh install of 12.04.  I logged in and tried to open the software center - it opens for only a few seconds, then it closes.  It happens whether I am in the root account or guest account.  There is no error message provided either.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center

sudo apt-get install software-center

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you!!  I didn't perform the last task though because when I upgraded to 12.10 before I had all sorts of problems........but the fix you provided resolved my problem! Thank you again!!!!